# 422 Session Interval Too Small While trying to connect by jsSIP to Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch, jssip

I am trying to have a call from the browser by jsSIP through Freeswitch.

[image]

The registration is passed.

[image]

[image]

When I call It sends an invitation packet. Freeswitch answers with an error.

[image]

I've found [a similar case](https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/issues/155) on the internet. I've configured Freeswitch appropriately.

[image]

But it does not help.

- FreeSWITCH Version 1.10.7-release~64bit (-release 64bit)
- jssip ^3.9.1

Answer (score 1):

It was the problem related to session expiration.  I did not find a way to set the interval at jsSIP client. I set the server interval ***less*** than the client asked(90), then it started working with minimum-session-expires=20

There is a description hot it is designed to work.
[RFC 4028 - Session Timers in the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4028#section-6)